# Are there any landline phones running Android?

Tags: hardware, customization

I'm looking for a landline phone (not necessarily cordless) which runs on Android and gives me the associated control, customisability, and for a bonus, market access. Does such a thing exist?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Apparently Yes. The Archos Smart Home Phone is an Android Phone priced at £130 in the UK:

http://www.androidcentral.com/archos-smart-home-phone-now-available-get-android-your-landline

Although the reviews on Amazon UK arent very good:

http://www.amazon.co.uk/Archos-501809-Smart-Home-Phone/dp/B005H0M8LW

Binatone iHome Phone iDect with DECT and Android Technology

http://www.amazon.co.uk/Binatone-iHome-Phone-Android-Technology/dp/B004EBV1GI

Currently unavailable (maybe its that good)

Comment: Thank you! That's interesting and disappointing at the same time :(

Comment: @Simon beat me too it again ;)

Comment: Hope it helps. In the next fews years it will really kickoff. Its only in its infancy at the moment :)

Answer (score 1):

The [iDECT iHomephone](http://www.argos.co.uk/static/Product/partNumber/5529830.htm) has Android.

I do not know whether or not it comes with Google Play however.

Comment: Thank you. The page does not mention that the phone runs on Android. But from the looks of it, it's the same as the Binatone in @Simon's answer.

Answer (score 1):

[Motorola also has a device](http://www.engadget.com/2012/04/03/motorola-hs1101-mbp2000pu-android-home-phone-fcc/) similar to the Archos Simon mentions, though they don't seem to be available for sale yet, despite clearing FCC approval back in April.

[Binatone](http://www.binatonetelecom.com/products/androidproducts) also offers such devices, though it appears to only be available in Europe

There's also Android-based VOIP units, like the Panasonic KX-UT670, though I imagine that isn't what you're looking for.

Comment: Thank you. Do you perhaps have a link or a name for the Motorola phone?

Comment: Info I've got is from engadget, who found it in an FCC filing.  http://www.engadget.com/2012/04/03/motorola-hs1101-mbp2000pu-android-home-phone-fcc/